# Post- ajax request to WebApi via jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently trying to do an Ajax request with jQuery to an WebApi.
I set up a database with the EntityFramework. My Problem is that the Ajax request is not send ( doesn't appear in Fiddler ) and i can't fint the reason.
I'm quite new to web Api but not to Aps.net with C#. I didn't check if the WebApi works.

My HTML- forms:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Neue Person eintragen</legend>
        <br/>
        <label for="inpVorname">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Vorname" id="inpVorname"/>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <label for="inpNachname">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nachname" id="inpNachname" />
        </label>
        <br/>
        <label for="inpAlter">
            <input type="number" min="14" max="110" step="1" value="40" />
        </label>
        <br/>
        <label for="butOne">
            <button id="butOne">Speichern!</button>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // click on button
        $('#butOne').click(function () {

            // get Values from input fields
            var fnameInp = $('#inpVorname').val();
            var lnameInp = $('#inpNachname').val();
            var ageInp = $('#inpAlter').val();

            //build Json
            var personJson = {
                Firstname: fnameInp,
                Lastname: lnameInp,
                age : ageInp
            }
            // send request
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'api/GetData/newEntry',
                data: JSON.stringify(personJson),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                succes: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("error again!");
                }

            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Data- Controller:

```
public class GetDataController : ApiController
{
    public string newEntry([FromBody] Person persobj)
    {
        // store result of SaveChanges- function ( number of saved entrys ) 
        int result;

        // Open context
        using ( var db = new PersonsDbModel())
        {
            // create new Object 
            var newpers = new Person();

            newpers.Firstname = persobj.Firstname;
            newpers.Lastname = persobj.Lastname;
            newpers.age = persobj.age;

            db.Persons.Add(newpers);
            result = db.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (result == 1) return "worked just fine!";
        else return "didn't save anything...";

    }
}
```

and the webApi Config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of webapi you are using?

Comment: In your browser, debug your client (JS code) and see what happens on the $.ajax row! Does your code enter the button event handler when you click it? Do you get any errors? It could be a CORS issue.

Comment: I'm using web api 2.

Comment: Maybe add error handling to get some insight: `error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }`

Comment: It reaches the event handler and the values are set just right. Only the age variable is undefined but it doesn't work either if i remove the age completely from the code.

Comment: @Michael_B I get an "Object" with a lot of parameters, all arguments and callers set to null.

Comment: Look, you are not providing us with enough information to help you. What errors are you getting? "Not working" does not tell us anything really. There are two options, either the ajax request is never sent, then there is an error in your JS code, or the ajax request is sent and the error is server side or the server rejects it for some reason.

Comment: Try `error:function(e) { console.log(e.status); console.log(e.responseText); }`

Comment: @Michael_B the console returns 0 (e.status) and undefined (e.responseText)

Comment: do you see any  HTTP status codes like `404` or `400` or `500` or `403` in the fiddler status column.

Comment: @Marcus I guess it's not sent because in Fiddler, the request doesn't appear. I don't get any specific error. Neither in the Browser console nor in  visual studio or from the jquery error handling .

Comment: At what row in your JS code then does the event handler stop to execute? It seems very unlikely that the error is nowhere. Does the ajax row execute or if not?

Comment: @venky Request header -> GET /index.html HTTP/1.1                                    response header -> HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified      Is that the request? Should be Post and another Url i guess

Comment: `error: function (res) {
                    console.log(res.statusText);
                }`

Comment: @Marcus It doesn't stop. It's completely executed, "jumps" over the succes part and into the error handler.

Comment: Ok.. so then.. modify your code to include the error parameter as described by @venky and tell us what the error is.

Comment: @Venky Just returns "error".

Comment: Make sure your webapi project is running. Otherwise those endpoints will not be accessible for ajax call.

Comment: also there is a spelling mistake `succes` for `success` call back.

Comment: @Venky It's runnign with debugger so i can see if the break point in the Controller is hit.

Comment: can you see `api/GetData/newEntry` call request in `fiddler` and i hope `hostname` for JS application and webapi are same.

Comment: also put `breakpoint` in `global.asax.cs` `application_start` event. Let's see if the call goes until there. If it's not going there then it's 100% problem with the `ajax` code.

Comment: @Venky removing typo didn't change anything. Application_Start is reached and executed. Should both be on the same localhost , there is an error: CS0103: The name 'pers' does not exist in current context, wich dissapears if the page is loaded (after Application_Start())

Comment: You are using ` url: 'api/GetData/newEntry',`  This assumes the hostname as same as JS application.  You need to store your webapi hostname in some variable and use it here  like  `url : {variable}/api/GetData/newEntry'

Comment: @Venky I just changed the url to : 
url:'http://localhost:63476/api/getdata/newentry' . 
If i send a requets to this url with Fiddler while the local server is running the web api code is reached. There is still nothing sent from the js code.

Comment: are you able to reach till `newEntry` action in webapi controller ?

Comment: keep updating your question with whatever changes you made. That helps any new person to understand it quickly.

Comment: @venky i',m going to edit my question. The code as i posted it just works fine but not in the Firefox. Opera, IE, Edge and Chrome send the request and it just works... still not in Firefox and still no error to find.

Comment: `Async` calls will not work in firefox. You need to pass `async:false` in your ajax request. Also this might be due to CORS. As the 2 host names are different. This is causing a cross domain call and which will not work unless you configure CORS in your code.

Comment: if you are sure that JS application and WebAPI will be deployed in the same server and given the same host name then you don't need to worry about it for now.  It will be fixed when these gets deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is a spelling mistake and the "id" of the number input field is missing in this state of code, the code basically works. It's been a problem with (my) Firefox Browser. If I test the project in Firefox, the requests are not send whereas it works fine in the other Browsers ( Chrome, Opera, IE, Edge ).

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled "success". In your code you spell it "succes", (I've done exactly the same thing...) try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // click on button
    $('#butOne').click(function() {

      // get Values from input fields
      var fnameInp = $('#inpVorname').val();
      var lnameInp = $('#inpNachname').val();
      var ageInp = $('#inpAlter').val();

      //build Json
      var personJson = {
          Firstname: fnameInp,
          Lastname: lnameInp,
          age: ageInp
        }
        // send request
      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/GetData/newEntry',
        data: JSON.stringify(personJson),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data) { //change spelling here
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("error again!");
        }

      });
    });
  });
</script>
```